# Show date range formula Excel

Tags: date, excel-formula

I currently have a date range manually typed into the following box taken from a single cell (A) which runs every day.

Is there a formula that I can use that this box automatically populates when I enter new dates going forward?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whUyQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where the two dates are placed, it would be like:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd-mmm-yy") &" - "& TEXT(B1,"dd-mmm-yy")
```

where the first date is in A1 and second date is in B1.

If you are wanting to produce a text output that shows a From-To based on the chronologically first and last date in Col A, then:

```
=TEXT(MIN(A:A),"dd-mmm-yy") &" - "& TEXT(MAX(A:A),"dd-mmm-yy")
```

Comment: I only have the one day in the one cell so would be running from A1 - A1439
Would the above formula still work?

Comment: Yes, this does work as just tested, however only going to cell A1439 gives me the date contained in that cell which is 31/08/21. 
What I would be looking for is something that would continue on from Cell A1439 for dates after 31/08/21.

Comment: @Steven - perhaps you can add more description to the question. It is not clear what your data look like and where you would want your output. From what you are saying, it sounds more like you have running dates in Col A that are manually updated and you want a formula that chooses the first and last dates (chronologically) from those dates and returns a text output with `FromDate - ToDate`. Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes. the dates are in chronological order in column A from (Example 18/07/19 - 29/08/21) which with the above formula would work. 
However the dates continue to move daily in order from 30/08/21, 31/08/21, 01/09/21, with the latest date being used as ToDate

Comment: hey @Steven - the min/max should work in that case. It will not look at the order, but the value.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks

Comment: @Steven - so is that the answer?

Comment: Yea the Min/Max worked and is exactly what I was looking for. 
Thanks again

Comment: @Steven - so, please mark it as the answer.